# Building C# console project from Linux terminal using Mono

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, console-application

I have [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/) installed on my Ubuntu machine. How could I build my C# console project from terminal. My objective is to write a Makefile.

I wish to find out the equivalent of:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:OutputPath=%~dp0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build) to build sln or csproj files. xbuild is bundled with a standard mono install.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `dmcs`, which is the .NET 4 Mono compiler, directly.  For details, see the [CSharp Compiler page](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler).